# What can cause a angularjs / signalr client to fall asleep?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, owin

I have an angularjs client (asp.net/mvc 5) that gets data from a SignalR hub. Everything is working fine, but I have noticed often when I come back to client after being away for a couple of hours, the client application (browser) are no longer being updated. If I reload, the page starts to update again. The backend has been alive during all this.

What could be possible causes for this falling asleep behavioir? 
The page requires authentication (owin auth). Could it be that the logged on users security token has expired and the page reload renews it?

Comment: Signalr will disconnect from its hubs if it cannot communicate with them for about 30 seconds (by default). 

I have found that this can happen during IIS app pool recycles (which happen about once per day by default)

Comment: Thank you. I will monitor for a correlation between those two events, but yes, it sounds very plausible.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that the connection is being disconnected during IIS app pool recycles. Thx James for pointing me in the right direction!